# Why $R^{n} - 0$ is not homeomorphic to $S^{n}$

Tags: general-topology

I know that $S^{n}- p$ is homeomorphic to $R^{n}$ and the fundamental group : $\pi_{1}(R^{n} - 0) = \pi_{1}(S^{n})$ but I can't prove they aren't homeomorphic . Anybody help me ? 
Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 7):

$\mathbb{R}^n-0$ is not compact unlike $S^n$.

Comment: Can you prove it ?

Comment: That $R^n-0$ is not compact? Obviously $a_k=(k,\ldots,k)$ does not have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: More generally, by Heinie-Borel, a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Comment: :( Oh sorry , I forgot Heine-Borel theorem , thank you .